# Why does getClass.getResourceAsStream(path) give empty InputStream in lift web

Tags: scala, lift

I tried below code :

```
val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(path)
println(stream.read())
```

It prints -1.
but when i tried to read image from above stream it gives image correctly.

```
val image = ImageIO.read(stream)
println(image.getHeight())
```

It prints correct height of image.. then why stream InputStream is empty ???

Comment: Is there no one who can answer this question ???

Answer (score 0):

To get a resource file from inside Liftweb you should use "LiftRules.getResource(file)".
This way it works both from inside a *.war package and from a normal folder.

For example,
    LiftRules.getResource(file).foreach(_.openStream().read())